# From symfony2 form to a simple form users get incorrect password

Tags: symfony

Originally creating a normal registration form (email + password) using the symfony form builder i found no problems at all registering my users.

For some technical issues and strategic stuff im not using any more the symfony form builder and i just made a common html form. The username, salt and password gets saved in database but when i tried to login it does not work, so the password or salt are wrong, and that makes me think that maybe the salt is created using a token send as a hidden field created by the symfony form builder, am i right?

So, originally since the symfony form builder allows you to parse the data directly into an entity i did something like this:

```
    if( 'POST' === $this->getRequest( )->getMethod() ) {
        $form->bindRequest( $this->getRequest( ) );

        if( $form->isValid( ) ) {
            $userSignup = $form->getData( );

             $user = $userSignup->getUser( );

             $user->setPassword( $this->_encodePassword( $user ) );
```

Now, since im using a normal form:

```
        if(isset($_GET['user_signup']['user']['username']) && $this->_validemail($_GET['user_signup']['user']['username'])) $username = $_GET['user_signup']['user']['username']; else die('BAD EMAIL');
        if(isset($_GET['user_signup']['user']['password']) && strlen($_GET['user_signup']['user']['password']) >= 5 && strlen($_GET['user_signup']['user']['password']) <= 20)  $password = $_GET['user_signup']['user']['password']; else die('BAD PASSWORD');

        $user = new user();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setPassword( $this->_encodePassword( $user ) );
```

The encodePassword function:

```
protected function _encodePassword(  User $user )
{
    $factory    = $this->get( 'security.encoder_factory' );
    $encoder    = $factory->getEncoder( $user );
    return      $encoder->encodePassword( $user->getPassword( ), $user->getSalt( ) );
}
```

Im re utilizing someone else code so maybe im having trouble understanding how encodePassword works.

Comment: check that salt exist and its not empty in your $user->getSalt()

Comment: Have you checked your encoders on your security.yaml? Did you used the same encoder algorithm for encrypting and decrypting passwords?

Comment: what could be the "strategic" reason for not using symfony2's form component?!

Comment: ... creating an html form without form builder, accessing GET parameters without request object ... whatever you're trying to do here .. you're doing it wrong. thx for the downvote on my answer providing a possible cause for the wrong username/password read from the request. deleted it

Answer (score 0):

If you want registration system in your web application install [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).

Then you can use the [userManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md) for create, register and edit any user.

Answer (score -1):

you should create a salt first (using some random function) and use `$user->setSalt($salt)` in your controller ...

... or generate the salt inside the User's `__construct()` method.

FOSUserBundle i.e. creates the salt in the constructor of the User object using:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    // ...
}
```

reference [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php).

Otherwise the encoder called at `$this->_encodePassword($user)` won't find the salt calling the user object's getter `getSalt()`.

---

**tip:**

In symfony2 you should never try to access `GET` parameters using `$_GET` ...

... use the [Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object instead.

Please read the [Symfony2 and HTTP Fundamentals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#the-front-controller) chapter of the book.